# Windows 8.1 Preview Store installation keeps trying to install

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-preview

I'm running Windows 8 Pro and I've tried to install Windows 8.1 Preview from the store. I got the 'Sorry, it looks like this PC can't run Windows 8.1 Preview' error. I looked it up and it appears I can't upgrade in place because I've moved my Users directory to another drive.

Fine, so be it. The only problem is that the Store keeps trying to install Windows 8.1 Preview every time it feels like doing so.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing so, or have I locked my Windows installation into a mortal embrace with an ever-failing installer?

Comment: Tried disabling Windows Update?

Comment: @ErikHeemskerk - Move the users directory to the original location, upgrade, then move the users directory back to the desired location.  I would of course wait until Windows 8.1 RTM is released in 2 months.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard I don't want to disable Windows Update. Also, I don't *want* to upgrade if this is the kind of problems I'm getting. I just want it to stop trying to upgrade.